# proving something is not a well formed formula

Tags: logic

Prove if $W$ is  well formed formula (wff) them $W$ cannot be written as $W_1W_2$ where $W_1$ and $W_2$ are wffs

$$\text{wff} :=\begin{cases} (A_i)\\
 (\sim x)&\text{if } x \text{ is a wff}\\
 (x>y)&\text{if }x, y \text{ are wffs}\end{cases}$$

I apologize if I am not expressing myself well, but the comment about concatenation of 2 wffs not being allowed is really the crux of my issue.  Why isn't this allowed? By the laws of a legal parenthesis string (lps) this is acceptable as long as what ever is inside of the two parentheses are lps themselves.  Isn't a wff an lps in it's own right?
Again, I am sorry, I'm sure this is probably simple but I always get caught up in the semantics of thing and want to make sure I am seeing things correctly.

Comment: This depends heavily on the particular definition of well-formed formula.

Comment: I rephrase the comment by Dunstan : if you want a satisfying answer, please ask an understandable question. If you are working in propositional logic, a plausible reading of your statement has a definite answer; something like : the operation of *concatenation* of formulas is not allowed; between two wffs you must interpose a binary connective, like : $\lor$, $\land$ or $\rightarrow$.

Comment: I tried to format the question towards legibility, but I'm not sure what to make of the last part. Also, what can be said about the $A_i$?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the concep of *well formed formula* depends on the language you are working with.

A language has a *syntax*, i.e. *rules* that allows you to "build" *terms* (i.e."names") and *expressions* (i.e."sentences").

If I assume that you are working in formalized arithmetic, usualy variable like "x" are terms standing for numbers; so, the expression $x > y$ is well formed. But, in this case $x$ and $y$ are **not** wff.

If instead we are working with the language of *propositional logic*, where the variables ($x$ and $y$) are called *sentential variables*, the expression $x > y$ is not well formed.

Again, we need to know what *language* are you handling.

About *concatenation*:

> but the comment about concatenation of two wffs not being allowed is really the crux of my issue.

If I work with *propositional logic*, the language is made by *sentential variables*, like $p, q, r, ...$ and truth-functional *connectives*, $\lnot$ (negation, unary), $\land$ (conjunction, binary), $\lor$ (disjunction, binary), $\rightarrow$ (conditional, binary).

The rules available to build expressions are (tipically) :

> *(i)* every *sentential variable* is a wff
>
> *(ii)* if $A$ ia a wff, then $\lnot A$ is a wff
>
> *(iii)* if $A$ and $B$ are wffs, then $A \lor B$, $A \land B$ and $A \rightarrow B$ are wffs
>
> *(iv)* nothing else is a wff.

Reviewing the above rules, you can see that there are **no** rules allowing you to juxtapose two wff without interposing a connective; e.g. :

> $AB$ and $\lor A$ are *not* wffs.

If you are working in first-order number theory, you have *individual variables*, like $x$ and $y$, you have the above *connectives*, you have the *equality* symbol and the *quantifiers*, (for simplicity, we assume that also $>$ is a *primitive* symbol).

The following are examples of wffs :

> $\forall x (x > 0)$ and $x = 0$

Again, you have rules like the above, that do not allow you to "build" an expression like :

> $(x = 0) \forall x (x > 0)$

But there are *languages* ($\lambda$-calculus) where concatenation is allowed; and then there are *programming languages* ...

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Show that the symbol sequence `)(` cannot occur in a wff but does occur in the concatenation of two wffs.