# What is a well built formula?

Tags: logic

I am just beginning with Propositional Logic, and trying to understand few concepts:   Well-built formula.

If $3 + 2 = x$ , $\sqrt{5} − 3 > 2$, $x^2 + 2x − 1 = 0$ are atoms, then:

$$((3 + 2 = x) \land  (x^2+ 2x − 1 = 0)) ⇒(\sqrt{5} − 3 > 2)$$ is a well-built formula

How ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to review the inductive cluses defining the set of *well-formed formulae*.

Tipically, we define the set of *atomic* formulae, like your : $3 + 2 = x$, and then we say that we can use them to build-up more "complex" ones by way of *connectives*.

Thus, if $\alpha, \beta$ are formulae, then also :

> $(\lnot \alpha)$, $(\alpha \land \beta)$, $(\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$

are fomulae.

See Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122384520) (2ed - 2001), page 16 :

> [We have an *alphabet* with] the five symbols
>
> > $¬, ∧, ∨, →, ↔$
>
> called *sentential connective* symbols.
>
> We have included infinitely many sentence symbols $A_i$.
>
> We want to define the well-formed formulas (wffs) to be the “grammatically correct” expressions.
>
> The definition will have the following consequences:
>
> *(a)* Every sentence symbol is a wff.
>
> *(b)* If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are wffs, then so are $(¬α), (α∧β), (α∨β), (α→β)$,
>   and $(α↔β)$.
>
> *(c)* No expression is a wff unless it is compelled to be one by (a)
>   and (b).

Comment: Thanks for the details. So we can say that αβ is  not a wff.

Comment: @gpuguy - right: unless you introduce an "abbreviation" stipulating e.g. that $\alpha \beta$ stand for the "formal" $(\alpha \land \beta)$. This happen when we "abbreviate" the formal $(\lnot x = y)$ with $x \ne y$.

Comment: @gpuguy - see also this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666379/proving-something-is-not-a-well-formed-formula)

Answer (score 2):

"Well built" is defined by rules like: if $\varphi$ is well-built, then so too is $\neg \varphi$; if $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are well-built, then so too is $\varphi \wedge \psi,$ etc. Furthermore, we stipulate that only the formulae that can be constructed according to these rules are well-built. This means that meaningless formulae like $\varphi \wedge (\neg)$ are not well-built.

Okay, but why bother?

We use the concept of a well-built formula to prevent "junk theorems." For example, one inference rule might read: "If $\varphi$ is written down, then we may write $\varphi \vee \psi$." Using this rule willy-nilly, we can deduce silly things. For example, perhaps $x=x$ is written down. Then we can deduce $(x=x) \vee (=x= x\neg).$ Such "junk theorems" are avoided by restricting the use of inference rules to well-built formulae.

Comment: the idea of identifying "Junk theorem" is very nice, and it gives me better reason to study this subject. Thanks.

Comment: @gpuguy, you're most welcome.